# Show one specific column assigned by ID in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, show

I have a database called "tekst".

There are 3 columns:

1. id (autoincrement),
2. date (timestamp),
3. tresc (text)

and the site: index.html.

I want to paste code like that `<?php echo "$id1"; ?>` into index.html to display a column "treść" assigned to some "id".

Now I do like that:

`$w = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tekst WHERE id=5"));`

`echo $w['tresc'];`

but when I have many records, it will be troublesome.

How to create MySQL Query to display what i want ?
In one page i will have many ID's.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: You can't add php code to html files! You have to create a `index.php` file instead of `index.html`.

Comment: "How to create MySQL Query to display what i want ?" So, what do you want? To display many records, or to display a single record?

Comment: What certainly you find troublesome? It's scarcely can be extracted from your explanations. Why not to post the very troublesome code and ask how to improve it? The code you posted at the moment perfectly answers the question from the title. So, what is the real problem?

Comment: Single record, precisely column "tresc", but specific by ID.

Comment: So make your assignation of id to a variable i.e. `WHERE id = $id` , so $id can be either POSTed by the user or something

Comment: Yes, but i want to have single index.php and there want to display data from mysql

Comment: @MateiMihai, Check your sources! Grzegorz, you can use PHP code in your .html file (if you got a linux server). Add a .htaccess file in your root with this code   'AddType application/x-httpd-php .html'

Comment: The problem will be when I have many content to show by ID, then i need to duplicate MySQL Query with id=1;id=2 etc.

Comment: Ferdi Duisters, yes i have in httpd.conf added already :) Thanks

Comment: What's the problem then? Use your action loopback to itself. For example you can make POST to the same page

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, but i want to have single index.php and there want to display data from mysql

Finally, from the comments it came clear.

Use query string to assign a variable. Address your script this way

```
index.php?id=1
```

then receive this variable using $_GET array

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

then format if for the SQL query

```
$id = intval($id);
```

then use it in the query

```
$sql = "SELECT tresc FROM tekst WHERE id=$id";
```